# Need date of latest input invoice by Vendor/Supplier

Tags: sql, db2

This query works. I´m trying to find the most recent date of Document input in our system.
The query below brings the date and supplier number, and it's working perfectly.

```
SELECT SUPPLIERNUMBER, MAX(DATEOFINPUT)
FROM TABLE A
WHERE COUNTRY IN ('661')
AND COMPANY IN ('01','40')
GROUP BY SUPPLIERNUMBER
```

Now, that information is great by itself, but I will also need additional information that it´s in another table B (the one that holds the information from the Suppliers, like Name, Short Name, Bank Data, etc)

```
SELECT B.COUNTRY , B.COMPANY ,B.SUPPLIERNUMBER, 
B.SUPPLIERNAME, A.DATEOFINPUT
FROM A
INNER B
ON A.COUNTRY =B.COUNTRY 
AND A.COMPANY =B.COMPANY
```

Here is where I don't know how to mix the 2 queries together. I understand I need from the first Query 2 columns of information: SupplierNumber and DateofInput.
With this information I have to join with the other table to get the Supplier information.

I'm not sure how to do this. I thought I had to do a subquery with MAX(DateofInput) but that way it will only bring 1 record of several with the same date, but no way to also bring the SupplierNumber.

Could you folk help me please?

This is for DB2, maybe some SQL syntax won´t work, not sure.

I only have user privileges, not admin access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporate the data fields from SUPPLIER table (B) into the `SELECT` and include them in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT A.SUPPLIERNUMBER,
       B.SUPPLIERNAME, B.COUNTRY, B.COMPANY, MAX(DATEOFINPUT) AS MAXDATE
FROM TABLE A
INNER JOIN SUPPLIER B
ON A.SUPPLIERNUMBER = B.SUPPLIERNUMBER
WHERE A.COUNTRY IN ('661')
AND A.COMPANY IN ('01','40')
GROUP BY A.SUPPLIERNUMBER, B.SUPPLIERNAME, B.COUNTRY, B.COMPANY
```

Comment: I get The grouping is inconsistent error. Im not sure why though it should work

Comment: Oh, it works according to the Table I chose from, I will try with more fields, will let you know

Comment: It's working. I have to note that for every field I add to SELECT I have to add to GROUPBY, otherwise it doesn't work.
Thanks kc2018!